# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'zlib'

Tags: node.js, docker

So a docker image can be build but when running the service it can't render anything. Following is console error,

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'zlib' from
>   'mathml/app/MathML/MathMLRenderer.js'.

The dockerfile consists:

```
FROM node:8

RUN mkdir /opt/service
ADD . /opt/service
WORKDIR /opt/service
ENV HOME=/root

RUN npm install && npm dedupe
ENV IN_DOCKER=1

EXPOSE 4000
CMD npm start
```

Seems like a dependency is missing? Although I added zlib in dependencies in package.json

Comment: could you please provide your package.json file content ?

Answer (score 1):

have you add the zib module, in the **package.json** using `npm install zlib`, after that when you do npm install, i guess it will works fine.

Comment: can you share the package.json file

Comment: Sure, I guess you want to see if zlib is included? Well in  "dependencies": { "zlib": "^1.0.5" }, is present.

Comment: Did you rebuild the container after adding it?

Comment: build the container image and select the respective container, follow the guidelines to build containter images 
https://www.scalyr.com/blog/create-docker-image/

Comment: @ShekharTyagi unfortunately not, I have the same error still